# How to use images as key for chart.js legend

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have built an internal KPI that uses salesman's names as the legend key at the moment, however I need to use their custom icons as a key with their respective colour border.

I have tried editing the chart.js options: legend field per the documentation, to no avail (see current options and datasets config below.)

```
datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "Salesperson1",
                        data:totalPointsSalesperson1,
                        fill:  false,
                        borderColor: 'blue',

                    },
                    {
                        label: "Salesperson2 ",
                        data:totalPointsSalesperson2,
                        fill:  false,
                        borderColor: 'red',
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Salesperson3",
                        data:totalPointsSalesperson3,
                        fill:  false,
                        borderColor: 'green',
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Salesperson4",
                        data:totalPointsSalesperson4,
                        fill:  false,
                        borderColor: 'yellow',
                    }
        ],
    },
    options: {

        legend:{
            position: 'right',
            display: true,
            labels: {
            padding: 150,
            },
        },
```

It seems that changing the point style on the chart is easy, but modifying the legend seems to be quite tricky. Perhaps im missing something blatantly obvious? One more thing to note as that this is a line graph.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to fob off the Chart.js legend config and decided to write my own, i'll close this question down.